# Blade not recognizing php using a different symbol for angular

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I use angular, and im trying to change the date format, blade is not recognizing the php that is being made

everything works but the created_at function

```
   <div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts ">
                <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.user.name %></div>
                <div class="panel-body panel">

                    <figure>
                        <p ng-model="post.body" editable-text="post.body" e-form="textBtnForm"> <% post.body %></p>
                        <p>   <% date('jS M, Y', strtotime(post.created_at)) %></p>
                    </figure>
                    <span>

                     <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)" ng-if="post.deletable"></i>


                          <button ng-if="post.update" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()" ng-hide="textBtnForm.$visible">
                            Edit
                          </button>

                        <span><button ng-if="post.update" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updatePost(post)">Update</button></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

my angular file has the following which works, but its not recognizing the date function, which results to blade not returning a date for it.

```
app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace angular's symbols or blade's?

Comment: no, im trying to render a date time keep in mind, im using `<% %>` for other content to render and it works but not for the created_at.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up server side code with client side code. `date` and `strtotime` are php functions and will not run in an angular environment.

You might want to look at client side date formatting libraries like [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment)

Answer (score -1):

filterUse this

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('mcFilters', [])
            .filter('mcDbDateFormatter', function() {
                return function(dateSTR) {
                    var o = dateSTR.replace(/-/g, "/"); // Replaces hyphens with slashes
                    return Date.parse(o + " -0000"); // No TZ subtraction on this sample
                }
            });
    }());
```

```
<p ng-bind="post.created_at | mcDbDateFormatter | date: 'shortDate'"></p>
```